# Magento 2.1- ACL Permissions not Working

Tags: magento2, configuration, permissions, user-roles, acl

I have created a **user** and given all the **required roles** to access the module. When we logged in with that particular user , we are able to see the module and module items but when we click on any item in the module we get the following output.

**Access denied
Please try to sign out and sign in again.
If you continue to receive this message, please contact the store owner.**

In controller index.php I have this method:

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{

    return $this->_authorization
                ->isAllowed('NAMESPACE_ModuleName::item');
}
```

Below is my **Acl**

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">

            <resource id="NAMESPACE_Xyz::xyz" title="NAMESPACE Xyz">
                <resource id="NAMESPACE_ModuleName::main_menu" title="Module Title" 
                                      sortOrder="100">
                    <resource id="NAMESPACE_ModuleName::manage_item" title="Manage Items" 
                              sortOrder="22" />   

            </resource>
            </resource>            
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                    <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                        <resource id="NAMESPACE_ModuleName::configuration" title=" Module Configuration" translate="title" />
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

The configuration file works for me but, when I click on the menu items , it says access denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You resource  id  is `id="NAMESPACE_ModuleName::manage_item"` so

**change**

```
return $this->_authorization
                ->isAllowed('NAMESPACE_ModuleName::item');
```

**to**

```
return $this->_authorization
                ->isAllowed('NAMESPACE_ModuleName::manage_item');
```